# How to delete the text between the tags of an XML element?

Tags: region

I need to delete a block of text between 2 tags, including tags themselves. I tried this:

```
(defun my-delete ()
      (interactive)
      (beginning-of-buffer)
      (search-forward "<%ARGS>")
      (move-beginning-of-line nil)
      (set-mark-command nil)
      (search-forward "</%ARGS>")
      (delete-region))
```

It selects the text, but `delete-region` doesn't work. When I click `del` it removes the text. What function should I use?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to delete the text between the tags or that text plus the tags or that text plus the tags plus the text on the line before the opening tag or...

Comment: You don't need to set the mark and activate the region. Just bind a variable (e.g. `beg`) to the position you reach where you want to begin the deletion; then move to the position where you want to end the deletion; then use `(delete-region beg (point))`. In general, you do **not** want to set the mark in a command you write, unless for some reason you want it to remain after the command is done.

Comment: @Drew I want to delete text + tags

Comment: Please put such info in the question. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got at the end:

```lisp
    (defun my-delete ()
      (interactive)
      (beginning-of-buffer)
      (search-forward "<%ARGS>")
      (move-beginning-of-line nil)
      (let ((begin (point)))
        (set-mark-command nil)
        (search-forward "</%ARGS>")
        (delete-region begin (point)))
      (kill-line))
```